# Declaring n element in Structure in C

Tags: c

While solving one of many programs at codechef and I encounter [a problem](https://www.codechef.com/JAN17/problems/CAPIMOVE) in which a single node can hold the address of any number of nodes. i.e. one node may have address of one node **or** two nodes ... or `n` nodes. So, I thought about using linked list. Now, the problem is I have learned only up to doubly linked list, so I can write programs in which I know how many addresses the node can handle.
Once I thought of this:

```
struct node
{
 int n ;
 for(int i=0;i<n,i++)
    struct addrs[i] ;
}
```

but it seems like illogical. So it would be of great help if someone can tell me how to write a structure in which a node can handle `n` addresses.

Comment: Or you just hold a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of `struct addrs` pointers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First here is what you want (you might need to add some cast depending on your compiler):

```
struct addrs;
struct node
{
   int n;
   struct addrs *a;
}


void init (struct *node, int n)
{
    node->n = n;
    node->a = malloc(sizeof(addrs)*n);
}

void destroy(struct *node)
{
    node->n = 0;
    free(node->a);
    node->a = 0;
}
```

---

Now, you have to understand why

```
struct node
{
 int n ;
 for(int i=0;i<n,i++)
    struct addrs[i] ;
}
```

does not work.

The `struct` keyword means you define a new type holding structured data. You cannot have any C executable code in it, so you cannot have a for loop in there.

Also the size of a structure must be known during compilation, were your example working, the size of the structure `node` would depends on `n` and could not be known before the program is executed.

Comment: We don't know what OP wants, the question is way to unclear.

Answer (score 0):

> once i thought of this ,
>
> ```
> struct node
> {
>  int n ;
>  for(int i=0;i<n,i++)
>     struct addrs[i] ;
> }
> ```

No, you can not use statements (like loops) to declare members of a structure. Besides, the size of a structure must be known at compile time, and can never change at run time.

> So , I thought about using linked list

Yes, a linked list is one possible way to implement this.

> now, the problem is I have learned only upto doubly linked list

This is not a problem. The knowledge of a doubly linked list is sufficient.

---

However, perhaps an array of pointers is a simpler alternative.

Since the size of your structure is static, but the size of the array may change at run time, you need to allocate the array dynamically, and store a pointer to it in the node.